# How to change time servers?

Tags: 11.10, ntp

I'm behind a firewall, so I can't access pool.ntp.org or Ubuntu's own time servers directly, and I'd like to change the time servers for my system. When googling, I find references to missing manpages like ntpd.conf(5) and ntpd(8), to a missing GUI for setting the time servers, and to a  cron script (`/etc/cron.daily/ntpdate`) that doesn't seem to exist on my system. I've also found a [reference](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+question/169696) to there being changes to `ntpd.conf`, so I'm hesitant to just create that file in `/etc`. How is one supposed to change the time servers in 11.10?

Comment: Perhaps you mean that you are behind a firewall, not behind NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of the GUI you mention, but all the missing files sound like they're part of the ntp package.

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

should install them, then you'll have /etc/ntp.conf which you can edit. Once done, do:

```
service ntp restart
```

to reload your new config. The command

```
ntpq -pn
```

will show you the list of servers it's using (and various stats).

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12, I had to use `sudo service ntp restart` 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/178968/how-to-configure-ntp-time-synchronization-on-a-server

Answer (score -1):

Most pools are set up to maintain time at the Stratum-12 to Stratum 16 level.  You will get best time when the system is set to use use the Master Clock in Boulder, Colorado, which will give either Stratum-1 or 2.

[NTP Server – Stratum Levels Explained](https://ntpserver.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/ntp-server-stratum-levels-explained/)

Excerpt:

> Network Time Protocol is a hierarchical protocol and is divided into
>   stratum which define the distance from the reference clock. A
>   reference clock source that relays UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)
>   time and has little or no delay is known as a stratum-0 device.
>   Stratum-0 servers cannot be used on the network, instead, they are
>   directly connected to computers which then operate as primary time
>   servers.
>
> A primary server that receives a time signal from a stratum 0 device
>   either through the GPS network or national time and frequency
>   transmission is known as a stratum-1 device. On a network a stratum 1
>   time server supplies the time to other devices on the network which
>   are known as stratum-2 devices. These also can be used as a time
>   source and equipment that connects to a stratum-2 device to receive it
>   become stratum-3 and so on.
>
> NTP can handle up to 16 different stratum levels, although the lower
>   down the hierarchy you go the less accurate the devices become.

---

Here is a Q&A that describes how to set it up:

[How do I set Ubuntu to use the primary time server time.nist.gov?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972799/how-do-i-set-ubuntu-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov/972800#972800)

The settings are in `/etc/ntp.conf` and there is only a few changes that need to be made.

First is to comment out the lines that specify the pools.

Then add this line instead:

[image]

Comment: What makes you say pools are terrible? I did a quick test now with `ntpd -d pool.ntp.org`, on a machine that has GPS clock. Result? `offset 0.000452 sec` Over a hundred queries, there was always three leading zeroes... That's pretty damn close to true time. And more than enough for any regular use!

Comment: I see consistently good times from those pools as well. That the pools is set up to provide stratum 12 to 16 is patently false. I use various pools as source, and it's rare to see a stratum three. And anyway - a stratum 3 *should* provide sub-second time. time.windows.com for instance is stratum 2. 0.debian.pool.ntp.org returns a stratum 2. Ubuntu pool returns a stratum 2...

Comment: I'll have to take your word on that.  For me, it fixed my machine-synchronization problems.  I did the same to all my Raspberry Pi-based data loggers so all the systems had the same source.  Now Filezilla just zips along, updating only the proper files.