# How to configure NTP time synchronization on a server?

Tags: server, ntp

I would like to configure my Ubuntu 12.04 server to synchronize its clock with a specific NTP server. Where to set this up?

Answer (score 40):

> Installation

[image: Install via the software center]

or if you prefer command line ...

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

> Configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

This file will probably have the default Ubuntu server activated. You can check http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/europe or http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/north-america or http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/asia for local (country based) servers. Just comment out all of the servers by adding a `#` in front of it and add in the one you want to use.

> Activating the new changes

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

> Checking if it synchs

```
sudo ntpq -c lpeer
```

This will show a list of all the servers and when they where last checked. Random example from the web:

[image]

> See logging

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

---

Do make sure, if you are using a firewall, to open UDP 123.

Comment: Why open up the port?  Stateful firewall will recognize request came from this machine outbound first, yes?

Comment: I used port 37 and that appeared to work?

Comment: Just in case the initial timezone was incorrectly set, the proper way to change it is to use the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` command.

Answer (score 11):

First, make sure that you have NTP installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Then edit the file below to add time servers.

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

To add time-servers to synchronize with, use [USA Servers](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/north-america) or [Europe Servers](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/europe).

Then,  restart NTP service

```
sudo service ntp restart
```