# How set the correct hour in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: date

I have an incorrect time in my Ubuntu server, I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04

When I run `date` command this is the result:

```
lun  8 set 2014, 08.28.03, CEST
```

The correct hour is 10.40.

Comment: Hmm weird our system is 2 hours off too?! Could be a problem with the time server and not your system :-X

Comment: If the timezone is correct, and you have a working internet connection, use `ntpdate` with a known NTP server (like `ntp.ubuntu.com`) to sync it.

Answer (score 4):

This is what solved the issue for me:

check for all timezones, and find yours

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

"America/New_York" matches my zone, so I ran this:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

...Then check the date

```
date
```

voilá

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware clock is probably set to UTC. To verify:
`grep UTC /etc/default/rcS`

This should give you something like:

```
# Set UTC=yes if your system clock is set to UTC (GMT), and UTC=no if not.
UTC=no
```

... with UTC being either yes or no. You probably need to configure this.

Read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178968/how-to-configure-ntp-time-synchronization-on-a-server) how to setup ntpd to always have the correct time.

Comment: I read this guide [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/NTP.html#ntp-status) and after it I run `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` and I have the correct hour now.. But I don't understand if my server update the correct hour every day automatically or no..

Comment: No, that was a one-time shot. You can add this command to the system crontab so it's executed periodically.